# How get all results of Invoke method

Tags: c#, .net

I have very simple delegate:

```
public delegate int Compute(int i, int j);
```

and some functions:

```
static int sum(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

static int diff(int x, int y)
{
    return x - y;
}

static int times(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}
```

Then I am declaring an event as:

```
public static event Compute e;
```

In main I am adding functions to event:

```
    e += new Compute(sum);
    e += new Compute(diff);
    e += new Compute(times);
```

And finally I would like write all results of function, so:

```
Console.WriteLine(e.Invoke(3,4));
```

As I understood `Invoke` method is invoking all function in event. But in my case I see the result only of the last added function - so `12`. How can I get all results of `Invoke` method ?

If functions aren't returning any type (they are void type) there is no problem, but if functions are returning something - there is.

Comment: This seems a bit [xy problemy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What problem are you actually trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call [`MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will allow you to invoke one handler at a time:

```
// TODO: Don't call your event e, and use Func<int, int, int>
foreach (Compute compute in e.GetInvocationList())
{
    int result = compute(3, 4);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} returned {1}", compute.Method.Name, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is by design. If you want to get all results you must get the list of delegates using GetInvokationList() method and then iterated by list and call all delegates.